# Which data types can be used when communicating with an App Service in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-app-service

I have created an UWP app with an app service and communication between those are done using value sets in an AppServiceConnection. I can however not find out what types of data that are supported in the value sets that are transferred.

Here is some test code

```
class MyClass { public int Prop1 { get; set; } }
var data = new ValueSet();
var stringlist = new List<string>() {"a string"};

// This does not work
// data.Add("data", new MyClass() { Prop1 = 1});

// This does not work
// data.Add("data", stringlist);

// This works fine!!
data.Add("data", stringlist.ToArray());
```

When using a not supported data type I get the error below, thus it is pretty clear that it is not supported. I can however not find any documentation around this and I cannot find out exactly what is supposed to be supported.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Data of this type is not supported.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007065E)
```

A second question; is it possible to create a class so that I can use it in the value sets?

Comment: You can include that doc says "This class prevents non-serializable types from being put into the map." but nowhere you can find what "serializable" types are.

Answer (score 1):

You can include all types that can be serialized. So any data type that has a default constructor that takes in `0` arguments and the fields inside them are also `serializable` or the ones that aren't serializable are `DataAnotated` as `[JsonIgnore]` are acceptable.

That being said, it's a safe bet to send in serialized data to the values.

To do so, you can use `NewtonSoft` nugget for `Json serialization` from the nugget package store and when you have the data that you need to send (if it's not a string) you serialize the object and then send it and when you receive it you'll get a serialized object that you can deserialize to get the data.